# why can't I declare a global variable inside an "exec" string

Tags: python, variables, runtime-error, exec, global

I am trying to declare and change a global variable in an exec string,  like this:

```
ostr = "didn't work"
nstr = "worked"
def function():
    exec("global ostr; ostr = nstr")
    #global ostr; ostr = nstr
    print(ostr)
    lv='ostr' in globals()
    print(lv)
    ostr='asd'

function()
```

However, this errors out on the print statement with:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ostr' referenced before assignment
```

But, if I comment out the "exec" line and uncomment line after the exec statement, the code works fine.

How can I fix this error using "exec"? I want to declare variables global and modify those global variables inside an exec string and have those modifications visible in "function" on subsequent lines.

Comment: Quite frankly, this sounds like all worst practices thrown together. While there are certainly answers as for *why* and maybe even as for how to "fix" it… I'd re-evaluate the entire approach of whatever you're doing here.

Comment: I am trying to implement a script in python. SImilar to a matlab script. Some other code that executes in the current workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare that you are using global ostr in the function to be able to print it. This piece of code outputs

```
def function():
   global ostr
   exec("global ostr; ostr = nstr")
   #global ostr; ostr = nstr
   print(ostr)
   lv='ostr' in globals()
   print(lv)
   ostr='asd'
```

> worked
>
> True

Edit: Just realised the exec actually works with global variables, if you re-run your code and print(ostr) in the global main you will see it was changed.

```
ostr = "didn't work"
nstr = "worked"
def function():
    #global ostr
    exec("global ostr; ostr = nstr")

function()
print(ostr)
```

> worked

Edit#2: Either declare ostr as a global variable before modifying it, or assign it to another local variable.

```
ostr = "didn't work"
nstr = "worked"
def function():
    exec("global ostr; ostr = nstr")
    #global ostr; ostr = nstr
    print(ostr)
    lv='ostr' in globals()
    print(lv)
        
function()
```

> worked

> True

Comment: The two things you mention here both do not get to what I am asking. As I mention in the original question, I realize that if I uncomment "global ostr; ostr = nstr" then the code "works" without using "exec". And I know if I remove the "print(ostr)" then there is no error. I am trying to use exec to declare something global, then use it. How do I do that?

Comment: Okay, I think I understand a bit more. It's actually your ostr='asd' that's throwing the error off since python thinks it's a local variable I suggest watching this to understand more https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVdf0LgmICw as for a fix I'd suggest re-assigning ostr to another variable if you want to modify it in the local scope, but you will have to declare it as a global variable to modify it in the global scope. Hope that helps

Comment: Anthony1223, it seems clear that "exec" simply ignores "global" commands. But your answers have provided me a workaround. If I have a separate line (not in an "exec") that declares variables global, then my commands in "exec" seem to work as intended. Thank you.                And thank you for taking the question seriously. Many times when I ask for Python help, people's answers consist of "Don't do that.", or "You shouldn't want to do that.", or "That's not Pythonic." or some other unhelpfulness.

Comment: You could trying passing globals() to the exec function. And don't worry about the "you're doing it wrong" thing, when I read that you're trying to migrate matlab code I know that it can be very annoying.